# Basic Algebraic Geometry (Silverman Elliptic Curves problem 2.3)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $\phi:C_1 \rightarrow C_2$ be a morphism of smooth projective curves over an algebraically closed field. One wants to show that $$[K(C_1):\phi^*K(C_2)] = \sum_{P \in \phi^{-1}(Q)}ord_P (\phi^*t_Q)$$ where $t_Q$ is a uniformizer at $Q$.

I started off by looking at the integral closure $B$ of the DVR $\phi^*K[C_2]_Q = A$. Then $B$ is a Dedekind domain and it is easy to check the field of fractions is $K(C_1)$. Thus if $M_Q$ is the unique maximal ideal of $\phi^*K[C_2]_Q$, and $M_Q$ factors in $B$ as $r_1^{e_1}\cdots r_n^{e_n}$, then $[K(C_1):\phi^*K(C_2)] = \sum_{i=1}^n e_i$ (since $B/r_i = A/M_q = K$).

It is easy to check that a subset of these maximal ideal factors includes all ideals of the form $M_PK[C_1]_P \cap B$ for $P \in \phi^{-1}(Q)$ and also that any two distinct elements of $\phi^{-1}(Q)$ yield different maximal ideals in $B$. Furthermore if $r_i = M_PK[C_1]_P \cap B$, then one can show using induction, localization, and short exact sequences that $e_i = ord_P(\phi^*t_Q)$. Thus if all maximal ideals of $B$ are of the form $M_pK[C_1]_P \cap B$, the theorem is proven.

How do you show all maximal ideals of $B$ are indeed of that form? I can't seem to figure it out and looking at similar questions there don't appear to be answers that directly address this problem.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4065947/vakil-exercise-17-4-d-different-notions-of-degree-of-a-finite-morphism/

Comment: That question uses the language of schemes so even if my question is basically the same it’s not obvious why that is the case.